# matplotlib customizing axes shadow

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to customize the axes shadow in a matplotlib plot. the shadow looks unpropotionate to the other patches i am adding to the plot. I need dx and dy to be at least 4 to show the perspective I am looking for. as the only parameter is a boolean axes there is no way to control the shadow depth. I am trying to create the Shadow object myself and adding it to the legend but its not working correctly.
please find herein an exemple

```
import wx
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.legend import Legend
from matplotlib.patches import Shadow
from matplotlib.axes import Axes
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        # initialize
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        # create main sizer
        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        # create figure, canvas and matplotlib toolbar
        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(4.5,4), dpi=None)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasWxAgg( self, -1, self.figure )
        # add canvas to sizer
        mainSizer.Add(self.canvas, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)
        mainSizer.Fit(self)
        self.Show(True)  

# create parabola data to plot
data = np.array(range(100))**2/100.
# start the plot
app = wx.App(0)      
frame = Frame()
axes = frame.figure.add_axes((0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8))
# add line 
line = Line2D(xdata=range(len(data)), ydata=data)
axes.add_line(line)
# set axes limits
axes.set_xlim(left=0,right=len(data))
axes.set_ylim(bottom=data[0],top=data[-1])
# create legend
l = Legend(axes,[line],['parabola'], shadow=False)
s = Shadow(l.legendPatch, 5, -5)
# add legend and shadow to axes
axes.legend_ =l
axes.add_patch(s)
# draw canvas                 
frame.canvas.draw()

app.MainLoop()
```

when the frame shows up on the screen the shadow is not drawn, It appear when I start resizing and sets behind the legend or near is in a weird way depending on how you resize.
this is a snapshot of my weird shadow before and after resizing

[image: This is the plot just when it got drawn before any resizing. no shadow!!!]

[image: This is the plot after some resizing. Shadow is disproportionate and resizes weirdly]